# An idiom or expression to show you are excited about something

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a better phrase, expression, idiom or word to show something is going to be *surprising*? I hope something will be more interesting, exciting and unexpected than just pure *surprise*.

For example,

> I'm pretty looking forward to tomorrow's Apple Event, I hope it will *give me a big surprise!*

P.S. I hope it can be used in the above example.

Comment: I'd say 'amazing', but that word is enormously over-used and its strength has been somewhat diluted.

Comment: With a little change to the sentence you might use 'get a charge out of".

Comment: @user116032 So I can use like "I hope I'd get a charge out of it"?

Comment: While you could use it that way, it would sound strange in the US.  I've used it only in  past tense as in "Man, I really got a charge out of that boat ride."  This is REALLY an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Astound. (Taken from Merriam-Webster)

adj. :  overwhelmed with astonishment or amazement :  astounded

v. : to cause a feeling of great surprise or wonder in (someone)

I'm *really* looking forward to tomorrow's Apple Event, and I hope it will be astounding!

(pretty is inappropriate in that example sentence)

Comment: As an American, "I'm pretty looking forward to" was never a phrase I heard. It sounds very awkward to me.

On the other hand, "I'm looking forward to" and "I'm really looking forward to" are very common.

Answer (score 1):

"delightful" - not really unexpected but maybe even better than expected.  I'm looking forward to the Apple Event, it will be delightful!

Answer (score 0):

How about: wow!<sup>[G](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+wow&es_sm=93&biw=1080&bih=1819&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0CAUQ_AUoAGoVChMIiJux7v3oxwIVA--ACh16RQou&dpr=1)</sup>

> exclamation
>
> 1. expressing astonishment or admiration.
>
> *"“Wow!” he cried enthusiastically"*
>
> synonyms:  holy cow, holy mackerel, holy moly, whoa
>
> noun
>
> 1. a sensational success.
>
> "your play's a wow"
>
> verb
>
> 1. impress and excite (someone) greatly.
>
> *"they wowed audiences on their recent British tour"*

I hope it would give me a wow!

Comment: I hope it can be used in my example, more than just a sentence. :)